# How to hide a highchars when there is no data to show?

Tags: highcharts

I created a time series chart using high-charts. For some scenarios there is no data to have a chart for them. 
Is there any way to hide the high-charts and don't show it at all when there is no data to show?

Comment: highcharts has a support for something similar. If there is no data to display, it just displays the method that there is no data to display(the message is customizable). [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/no-data-to-display/no-data-pie/) is an example. **NOTE** you need to have `no-data-to-display.js` imported

Comment: You could not create a chart if you have no data. If data is changing dynamically to some point in which there is no data, then please specify what do you expect to see: blank space with no chart? no chart and no div  for the chart? You could change visibility of chart's div or remove chart's div (if you care about memory you should call chart.destroy() too).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, using HTML and jQuery. You can put the chars inside a `div` and if there is no data you can use jQuery to hide the `div` where the chart is.

Something like this would work:

HTML code:

```
<div class="chartIsInside">
    <!--chart here-->
</div>
```

JavaScript code (using jQuery):

```
if(data === null){ //or empty or whataver
    $('div.chartIsInside').hide();
}
```

There are effectively a billion ways of doing this, this one seems the most simple to me.